# Show for $A$ normal, $A^* = P(A)$ for some polynomial $P.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $A$ is a normal $n \times n$ matrix with complex entries, $A^* = P(A)$ for some polynomial $P(x)$ with complex coefficients.  $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A.$

I feel like the proof is short and possibly involves the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, but I haven't had any luck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda_j$, $j=1\ldots k$ be the distinct eigenvalues of $A$, and $P(z)$ a polynomial with $P(\lambda_j) = \overline{\lambda_j}$.  Then $A^* = P(A)$.  The proof is easy, given that a normal matrix has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding what was meant.  Consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&i\\-i&1 \end{pmatrix}.$  Plug this into $P(x) = {\bar x}$ and the equality is not satisfied.

Comment: ^This polynomial sends A's eigenvalues $1 \pm i$ to $1 \mp i,$ as suggested.

Comment: $\overline{x}$ is not a polynomial in $x$.  The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $2$, not $1 \pm i$.

Comment: But if you did take a normal matrix with eigenvalues $1 \pm i$, such as $A = \pmatrix{1 & i \cr i & 1\cr}$, then the polynomial $P$ could be $P(x) = 2 - x$, and indeed $P(A) = 2 I - A = \pmatrix{1 & -i \cr -i & 1\cr} = A^*$.

Comment: Its all clear to me now, I think I was trying to work the problem in the wrong direction.  Thanks a bunch.